# Dataset of English verb forms (conjugation)

Tags: english, conjugation, datasets

What are some exhaustive/accurate datasets of English verb forms? From [this closed SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8424806/395857), I see:

- [GCIDE_XML](http://www.ibiblio.org/webster/), which contains plurals, alt spellings and conjugations, and  is in XML format.

Need to be scraped and/or parsed:

- On Wikipedia: [Category:English irregular verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_irregular_verbs), [List of English irregular verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs): table of irregular verbs with their conjugations
- [Reverso Conjugation](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-find.html); [Verbix](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/find.html)
- [English Verb Conjugation and Inflectional Morphology](https://www.scientificpsychic.com/verbs1.html)

What other datasets exist?

Comment: Including transparent & productive concatenations like "pranked", "prankee", or only the lexicalized stuff?

Comment: @user6726 I'm open to both

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the COBUILD wordform corpus in CELEX, which is now freely available through [WebCelex](http://celex.mpi.nl/).

The interface is horribly unintuitive, but you can use the "Create Lexicon > English Wordforms" option to create a database of inflected verb forms linked to their lemmas, plus inflection information and frequency.

Answer (score 1):

For a recent project for my university on a similar topic we made use of the [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/). Using a parser, you could easily look up a verb (or any word) by using the URL of the query function, e.g.:

```
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/search/english/?q=created
```

The results display British English and American English transcriptions and conjugations. Words that are spelled the same but are different parts of speech are located on different pages, for example:

```
start (verb): https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/start_1
start (noun): https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/start_2
```

This means that if one needs to get information for a specific verb, they could check the type specified on the page and if it's not the one they're looking for, they could iterate the number in the URL until HTTP 404 is returned.

While not pretty, I've got some code that might help with parsing the content of the Oxford Learner's Dictionaries on the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/Elhitch/transcriber).